# Prove DeMorgan's Theorem for indexed family of set using logic quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I need to prove both general union and intersection for indexed family sets using logic quantifiers, this is the prove i've written but i'm not sure if its correct:
[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: It is not correct.

Comment: Can you give a hint how to write it correctly.

Comment: **Hint :** you have to proceed step-by-step, separating the "unpacking" of $\cup$ and $\cap$ from the "complementation", and try to use the quantifier consistently... For the first one, form left to right : $x \in \cup A_i^C$ means that ("union") $\exists i \in I$ such that $x \in A_i^C$, i.e. $\exists i \in I$ such that $x \notin A_i$. This is : $(\exists  i \in I)(\lnot x \in A_i)$ which is equivalent to : $\lnot (\forall i \in I) (x \in A_i)$. In turn, $(\forall i \in I) (x \in A_i)$ is ("intersection") $x \in \cap A_i$ ; we have to restore the $\lnot$ and it's done (1 of 4 ...)